# Hyperbolic manifolds that are quotient of hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

If $M=\mathbb{H}^n/\Gamma$ is a hyperbolic manifold ($\Gamma$ being a group of isometries of $\mathbb{H}^n$) can I conclude that it is complete?

I know that if the covering map was a local isometry then $M$ would be complete. But since $M$ is a hyperbolic manifold, it is locally isometric to $\mathbb{H}^n$. However, I am not able to conclude that the covering map is a local isometry, and I have not found any counterexample.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Ordinarily the *meaning* of the statement "$M = \mathbb H^n / \Gamma$ is a hyperbolic manifold where $\Gamma$ is a group of isometries of $\mathbb H^n$" is that the Riemannian metric on $M$ is the one induced by the covering map $p : \mathbb H^n \to M$, and this does indeed imply that $p$ is a local isometry. Is it that final implication you are asking about?

Comment: Yes it is that final implication. I am sorry, my question seemed silly even to me, but I did not fully understand the reasoning. Thank you!